# Should I separate my API component from my Dashboard component?

Tags: php, frameworks, coding-style, components, laravel

I'm starting a somewhat large new project. It'll have two following two components (among others): API and dashboard. Clients will use the dashboard to import and organize their data and will use the API to access it remotely.

Essentially these two components will be using the same model classes and services but will build a different access point on top of them. My question is the following: 
Should I (1) build the two components as part of the same project sharing a repository and a directory or (2) build them in different projects and share the model as a third component?

1. should be easier to manage because everything is already in one place. However I will have to deploy both of them always and would not actually have a good separate of API server and Dashboard server.
2. on the other hand would allow me to have servers with different responsibilities, but I'll have to manage a third component.

What is the best way to go about this?

If you have experience with the Laravel framework how would implement the different modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have no experience with laravel, but since a some time with Zend Framework 2. For developing I use the approuch of domain driven design + MVC.

My suggestion is use the first approach.

**1. Code is better to maintain**

If you want to change something you only have to change 1 thing in one place and it will be done. Not in all you shared copies

**2. Server**

You worry about that you need a second server so you can dedicated taskes to a server. Well unless you have really big tasks (like sending millions of mails to clients per hour) then you should not worry about a dedicated server for a specific task.

Just put a load balancer in front of the server. This way when alot of api calls come in but no dashboard, you still use both servers, and not 1 is relaxing.

**3. maintain**

If there would become a third something (dashboard, api, site?) then you could easily expand with the current code base without alot of changes.

tl;dr I recommend the first one